# Proving C[0, 1] be polygonally connected

Tags: general-topology, analysis, path-connected

I am trying exam questions of another Institute in topology because my instructor was terrible.

I need help in proving following question -> Question 5

[image]

Can someone please tell how can I prove it.  I have no clue regarding this.

Comment: Can you prove any open set in  $\mathbb R^2$ is polygonally connected?  Will the same method work on $C[0,1]$?  I would guess that the $\mathbb R^2$ case had been one in class before this, and then the $C[0,1]$ case was put on the exam.

Comment: @GEdgar how to deal with the case when open set is counatble union of open balls? How to show that the path has finite number of line segments?

Comment: *Hint* A locally path-connected space is path-connected if and only if it is connected.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Theorems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $p(t)=tg + (1-t)f$ is continuous ($[0,1] \to C[0,1]$) and is a path from $f$ to $g$ in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: So it's path connected but how will you prove that it is connected by a finite number of line segments? You don't know what are functions f and g and so how p(t) must be a line segment?

Comment: @TimGreen by definition a path like this *is* a line segment. And 1 is finite.

Comment: I didn't knew that. Ok!!

Comment: @TimGreen study the definitions before you attempt a question. You must have learnt what a line segment is in a vector space.